# cannot read property 'data' undefined

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to get ag-grid row data for editing in a modal window.
during render vue throughs the bellow error.

[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined"

my code. This is the mounted method.

```
mounted() {
    this.leadsData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.params.data))
},
```

Comment: how are you passing the data you want to retrieve? If you are using route parameters you need to use this.$route.params.data

Answer (score 0):

**this.params must be a variable present in the data function**,
 otherwise, if you look for a property in the **url** you can use
**this.$route.params.data** or **this.$route.query.data**